# calculation of paramters needed for joint probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution

[image]

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

From my understanding, the number of entries in the above image is 7 because you need to calculate 7 and the 8th one can be done by 1-p.

But I can't understand how total number of parameters needed is `2*(2^3 - 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists some abuse of notation I think. As far as I see, it is asking for the joint distribution, so, the column heading should be $P(X_1,X_2,X_3|Y=i)$. There are $8$ combinations of $X$, and therefore we need $7$ of them as you say, to completely know the class conditional joint density. But, you also need an additional $7$ values of $P(X_1,X_2,X_3|Y=j)$ for each other class $j$, because $P(X_1,X_2,X_3|Y=0)$ and $P(X_1,X_2,X_3|Y=1)$ don't need to add up to $1$.

Comment: Oh yaa! I guess thats why it's given `total number of parameters needed = 2*(2^3 - 1)` , this considers `Y = j` the result is 14